# Rails Ruby - Handeling Nil in production vs development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, null

I launched my site with phusion passenger on a server and everything seems to run smoothly exept one page.

Here I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in Identities#show

Showing /var/www/feedme/app/views/identities/_platemenu.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass


10: <div id="plate_heading_box">
11:     <p class="plates_head">
12:             
13:             <%@params=@myp.collect{|i| i.to_i}%>
14:             <%@allsecondary=@plates.collect(&:id)%>
15: 
16:             <%if @startup != 1%>
```

It seems like the instance variable @myp doesn't work in production, because it works perfectly fine when I test it on my own computer in development. The variable is first declared in my controller:

```
 if params[:plates]!=nil
   @myp = params[:plates]
 else
   @myp = Array.new
 end
```

Not really sure why it doesn't work, any clues?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
    If I move the controller code out to the view it works... I wish the site would read the controller first ....

Comment: These are disparate pieces of code. What controller is your `@myp` assignment in? And what view is handled first after the assignment? The view code you're showing is for a partial, so I suspect there's another view erb that is hit first. Perhaps something happens along the way to `@myp`.

Comment: If you get `undefined method for nil:NilClass` this ALWAYS mean that you're not setting up some var properly. Double check your code, and mind it's not worth SO question.

Comment: But if I set it up the variables incorrectly why does it work in development?

Comment: It is possible that your dev DB does not have a particular entry that your production DB does.

Comment: Wow, look at lines 13, 14 and 16. Learn to use spaces correctly in your code. It's a readability and maintenance need.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is actually on line *14*, where you call `collect` on `@plates`, which doesn't appear to be initialized anywhere.